# Angular 8 unit test directive which includes setTimeout

Tags: angular, jasmine

I have the following simple autofocus directive:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appAutoFocus]',
})
export class AutofocusDirective implements AfterContentInit {

  @Input() public appAutoFocus: boolean;

  public constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

  public ngAfterContentInit() {
    if (this.appAutoFocus) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.el.nativeElement.focus();
      }, 300);
    }
  }
}
```

I'm now trying to write some simple unit tests, but 2 out of the 3 tests fail.

```
@Component({
  template: '<input type="text" [appAutoFocus]="true" />'
})
class TestComponent {
  constructor() { }
}

fdescribe('AutoFocusDirective', () => {
  let component: TestComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestComponent>;
  let inputEl: DebugElement;
     beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          declarations: [
            TestComponent,
            AutofocusDirective
          ]
        });

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        inputEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input'));

        spyOn(inputEl.nativeElement, 'focus');
        fixture.detectChanges();
      });

      it('should create an instance', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
      });

      it('should call the focus event', fakeAsync(() => {
        tick(400);
        fixture.detectChanges();
        fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
         expect(inputEl.nativeElement.focus).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
      }));

      it('should autofocus the input control', () => {
        const debugEl: DebugElement = fixture.debugElement;
        expect(debugEl.query(By.css('input:focus'))).not.toBe(null);
      });
```

"Should call the focus event" fails with `Spec 'AutoFocusDirective should call the focus event' has no expectations.`

"Should autofocus the input control" fails with `Expected null not to be null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way i could get this to work was to add a setTimeout to the test spec, so it now looks like so:

```
  it('should call the focus event', (done) => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    setTimeout(() => {
      expect(inputEl.nativeElement.focus).toHaveBeenCalled();
      done();
    }, 500);
  });
```

To be honest, it's a garbage solution but i've wasted too much time on this.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else coming to this, I wrote the same component and got the tests to work by moving the first `fixture.detectChanges()` outside of `beforeEach` and into the test cases.

I think the issue is that this needs to happen within the context of a `fakeAsync`. Then I was able to remove the `fixture.whenStable()` call as well. My test case looks like:

```
it("should set focus to the attached element.", fakeAsync(() => {
    // Given
    fixture.detectChanges(); // Moving this outside of fakeAsync breaks tests.

    // When
    tick(400);

    // Then
    expect(inputEl.nativeElement.focus).toHaveBeenCalled();
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can't couple `fakeAsync` with `fixture.whenStable`.

Try:

```
      it('should call the focus event', fakeAsync(() => {
        tick(400);
        fixture.detectChanges();
        // You should check out `flush` method to resolve instead of specifying the time in the argument of tick
        expect(inputEl.nativeElement.focus).toHaveBeenCalled();
      }));

     it('should autofocus the input control', fakeAsync(() => {
        tick(400);
        fixture.detectChanges();
        const debugEl: DebugElement = fixture.debugElement;
        expect(debugEl.query(By.css('input:focus'))).not.toBe(null);
      }));
```

Both of your tests do the same thing so consider putting them both in one `it` block.

A good read for you: https://alligator.io/angular/testing-async-fakeasync/

Comment: I've read the Alligator article. I've tried the suggested changes, including swapping out tick for flush, but the tests still fail.

Comment: In the `setTimeout` callback, put a `console.log('In the set timeout')` and put a `console.log('inside of the if function')` and make sure both logs are seen.