# timeout function inside directive not called

Tags: angular, typescript, jestjs

I wanted to test a simple AutoScrollDirective.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appAutoScroll]',
})
export class AutoScrollDirective implements AfterViewInit {
  constructor(private element: ElementRef<HTMLElement>) {}

  @Input()
  delay = 100;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    setTimeout(
      () => this.element.nativeElement.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start', inline: 'nearest' }),
      this.delay
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see, it countains a setTimeout. I thought this could be handled with a fakeAsync.

```
@Component({
  template: `<div appAutoScroll></div>`,
})
class TestAutoScrollDirectiveComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {}
}

describe('AutoScrollDirective', () => {
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestAutoScrollDirectiveComponent>;
  let component: TestAutoScrollDirectiveComponent;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [AutoScrollDirective, TestAutoScrollDirectiveComponent],
      imports: [BrowserDynamicTestingModule],
    });

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestAutoScrollDirectiveComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should call scrollIntoView of the element', fakeAsync(() => {
    const scrollIntoViewMock = jest.fn();
    HTMLElement.prototype.scrollIntoView = scrollIntoViewMock;
    component.ngAfterViewInit();
    tick();
    expect(scrollIntoViewMock).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }));
});
```

However, the function inside the timeOut is never called. After some debugging, I found out it reaches ngAfterViewInit and call setTimeout but nothing happens.

### Edit:

I've tried out the solution to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60263472/angular-8-unit-test-directive-which-includes-settimeout), but I agree that it's not a suitable one. It'll work for now but I'll keep this open so a better one can be found.

Comment: ngAfterViewInit isnt a lifecycle hook of directives, its for components only

Comment: It is, as described in the [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
tick(101);
```

instead of

```
 tick();
```

Comment: Nope, nothing changed. Still doesn't call the function.

Comment: Could you tell me what is the outcome of the test, Does it fails and with what error?

Comment: Expected calls >= 1
Received calls = 0